# Filtering data and showing loader, but first the browser freezes, then the loader is shown and immediately disappears, async function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, search, loader

I want to show loader when user clicks search but I have a problem with screen loader or rather with nature of JavaScript’s single-thread. Browser doesn’t get a chance to update the UI even if I put the loader before filtering. Button is clicked, then the browser waits 2-4 seconds (freezes), then the data is filtered, then the loader shows for half a second and it disappears. How can i resolve problem so that loader is shown when button is clicked before data starts filtering and that my browser does not freeze?

I tried like this with Promise but it is not working. I found some examples of turning my code to asynchronous but none of them helped, even with tiny delay to show loader is not working. This is the last example that I tried.
I am using this loader library [https://gasparesganga.com/labs/jquery-loading-overlay/](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
//function for filtering
function filter(searchSplit) {

$('.parent').LoadingOverlay("show");
var button = $(this);
button.attr('disabled', true);

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function () {
    
        $(".table tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function (e) {
            $(this).attr('visible', 'false');
            if (!$(this).parents('.parentEl').hasClass('.foundParentEl')) {
                $(this).parents('.parentEl').addClass('hide');
            }
            if (searchSplit.length > 4) {
                $(this).parents('.list').removeClass('show');
            }
        });

        $(".table tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function (e) {
            $(this).attr('visible', 'true');
            $(this).parents('.parentEl').removeClass('hide');
            if (searchSplit.length > 4) {
                $(this).parents('.list').addClass('show');
            }
        });

        var empty = $(".table tbody").not(':has(tr)');

        if (searchSplit.length > 4) {
            empty.parents('.parentEl').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {
            empty.parents('.parentEl').removeClass('hide');
        }

        if (searchSplit.length > 4) {
            $(window).trigger('resize');`your text`
        }

        resolve();  
    }, 0);
})
.then(() => {
    // This will run after your code is done
    button.attr('disabled', false);
    $('.parent').LoadingOverlay("hide");
});`


}

//click event on button
$('.btn-search').click(function () {
    var searchTerm = $(".search").val();
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('");
    filter(searchSplit); //calling function
});
```